# Android: safe way to hide navigation spinner in ActionBar?

Tags: android

I would like to show a spinner in my ActionBar, using `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST`, but I would like it to hide/show based on some application context.  I have found that I can remove it from the ActionBar with `getActionBar().setNavigationMode(-1)`, however I don't know if this is a good idea.

Any feedback on if this is safe or if there is a safer alternative?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe this is more accepted:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: the goal is display the navigation spinner, and then hide/show it as needed.  this only shows it?

Comment: @ab11: `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD)` will remove the effects of `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)`. I do not quite know why the `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` is in the code snippet, though.

Comment: My assumption was that @ab11 wanted to have a completely empty ActionBar (no title, no navigation).  If the title should remain, then simply drop off the `setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`

Comment: Oh, I was also thrown by that but now understand.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you stick to `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST`, you will have to set navigation listener every time you want to show your spinner back. That is obviously not the best soluton.

Instead, you may want to use `ActionBar.setCustomView()` to set spinner navigation ([reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28android.view.View%29)).

Here is some sample code where you set the spinner:

```
Spinner navigationSpinner = new Spinner(this);
navigationSpinner.setAdapter(yourSpinnerAdapter);
// Here you set navigation listener
navigationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(yourSpinnerNavigationListener); 
getActionBar().setCustomView(navigationSpinner);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Then, when you want to show/hide it you simply change it's visibility:

```
getActionBar().getCustomView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your implementation of `ActionBarDrawerToggle` like this:

```
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        if (slideOffset == 0) { // 0 = drawer is closed             
            setActionBarNavigationVisibility(activity, true); //show Tabs when Drawer is closed             
        }
    }

public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
        super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
        //hides Tabs right after Drawer starts opening
        if (DrawerLayout.STATE_DRAGGING == newState || DrawerLayout.STATE_SETTLING == newState) {
            setActionBarNavigationVisibility(activity, false);
        }
    }
```

Where method `setActionBarNavigationVisibility` is considering all navigation modes (you can delete code for unnecesarry navigation modes):

```
public static void setActionBarNavigationVisibility(Activity activity, boolean visible) {
    try {
        /* 1. --- If the navigation items are showing in ActionBar directly. We have 3 options Spinner, Tabs, and CustomNav ---
         (When Tabs are showing BELOW ActionBar, is handled at the end) */
        int actionViewResId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar", "id", "android"); // @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023483/how-to-get-actionbar-view
        View actionBarView = activity.findViewById(actionViewResId); // returns instance of com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView (inaccessible)
        if (actionBarView != null) {
            int visibility = visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE; // not GONE, so it still takes space in ActionBar layout

            // handle tabs navigation
            Field mTabScrollViewField = actionBarView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTabScrollView");
            if (mTabScrollViewField != null) {
                mTabScrollViewField.setAccessible(true);
                View mTabScrollView = (View) mTabScrollViewField.get(actionBarView); // instance of com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView (inaccessible)
                if (mTabScrollView != null)
                    mTabScrollView.setVisibility(visibility);
            }

            // handle Spinner navigation
            Field mSpinnerField = actionBarView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSpinner"); // resp. mListNavLayout
            if (mSpinnerField != null) {
                mSpinnerField.setAccessible(true);
                View mSpinner = (View) mSpinnerField.get(actionBarView); // instance of android.widget.Spinner
                if (mSpinner != null)
                    mSpinner.setVisibility(visibility);
            }

            // handle Custom navigation
            Field mCustomNavViewField = actionBarView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCustomNavView"); // resp. mListNavLayout
            if (mCustomNavViewField != null) {
                mCustomNavViewField.setAccessible(true);
                View mCustomNavView = (View) mCustomNavViewField.get(actionBarView);
                if (mCustomNavView != null)
                    mCustomNavView.setVisibility(visibility);
            }
        }
        // 2. --- If the Tabs are BELOW ActionBar (narrow screens) ---          
        ViewParent actionBarContainer = actionBarView.getParent(); // parent of ActionBarView is com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer (inaccessible)
        Field mTabContainerField = actionBarContainer.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTabContainer");
        if (mTabContainerField != null) {
            mTabContainerField.setAccessible(true);
            View mmTabContainer = (View) mTabContainerField.get(actionBarContainer);
            if (mmTabContainer != null)
                mmTabContainer.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE); // now use GONE, so the mTabContainer below Actionbar does not take space in layout
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO Handle exception...         
    }
}
```