# How to get ActionBar view?

Tags: android, view, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, showcaseview

I'm using the `Showcase` library to explain my application feature to
the user. In some point I need to dim the whole `ActionBar` to present 
another feature to the user.

For that I'm using the `setAlpha(float num)` of the `View` class. And so for doing that I need to get the actual view instance of my `ActionBar`

By the way, I'm using the `support-7-appcompat` library that gives ActionBar support for older systems.

### Update

In the meantime I found this option, if you configure a custom view and add it to you `ActionBar` using:

```
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

Then to get the `View` of the `ActionBar` you could do:

```
(View) activity.getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().getParent().getParent()
```

Is there a simpler or easier way to do that?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yep. You can actually get the view by using this function:

```
public View getActionBarView() {
    Window window = getWindow();
    View v = window.getDecorView();
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", "android");
    return v.findViewById(resId);
}
```

Pretty much the way this works is that the actionbar container uses the id `android.R.id.action_bar_container`, but this id is not public. Therefore we use getIdentifier() to retrieve this id and then the rest is simple.

Comment: What if I'm using actionbarsherlock?

Comment: @ThuyTrinh i think its `abs__action_bar_container`for actionbarsherlock

Comment: @ThuyTrinh you can check my extended answer

Comment: Doesn't work in Android 2.3 with ActionBar Compat, but works with getPackageName() instead of "android".

Comment: On `support-library-v7-r21.0.3` using `ActionBarActivity` and `Theme.Appcompat`, `v.findViewById(resId)` returns `null`. `resId` is valid though. Any suggestion.

Comment: I don't know what's the need to get the decor view when activity.findViewById will do the whole wrap!!!

Comment: Can this be referenced directly in `xml`? For example, if I want another widget (eg a listView) to align to the bottom of the actionBar when I have made the actionBar float on top of the contents like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726214/transparent-actionbar-custom-tabcolor)?

Comment: I find the ActionBarContainer view, but the LongClickListener doesn't work on API 24, any ideas??

Answer (score 8):

I think this solution is more complete, handling both normal Activity and ActionBarActivity.

It also handles the case that the actionbar was set using a toolbar, but you need to implement it in the activity you've created:

```
public static View getActionBarView(final Activity activity) {
    if (activity instanceof IToolbarHolder)
        return ((IToolbarHolder) activity).getToolbar();
    final String packageName = activity instanceof ActionBarActivity ? activity.getPackageName() : "android";
    final int resId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", packageName);
    final View view = activity.findViewById(resId);
    return view;
}

public interface IToolbarHolder {
    public android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar getToolbar();
}
```

Comment: there is no need to use `final View v = window.getDecorView();`,  you can use `activity.findViewById` instead.

Comment: @MoshErsan Seems correct. maybe I've got it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 6):

for **support.v7** getActionBarView(ById) doesn't work.

this returns actionBar Toolbar :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewGroup actionBar = getActionBar(getWindow().getDecorView());
    TextView actionBarTitle = (TextView) actionBar.getChildAt(0);
}

public ViewGroup getActionBar(View view) {
    try {
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;

            if (viewGroup instanceof android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) {
                return viewGroup;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                ViewGroup actionBar = getActionBar(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));

                if (actionBar != null) {
                    return actionBar;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Good solution to achieve Toolbar instance.

Answer (score 5):

I made a little fix on @idunnololz code to support ActionBarSherlock

```
private View getActionBarView() {

    int actionViewResId = 0;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        actionViewResId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                "abs__action_bar_container", "id", getPackageName());
    } else {
        actionViewResId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(
                "action_bar_container", "id", "android");
    }
    if (actionViewResId > 0) {
        return this.findViewById(actionViewResId);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: It returns null if I use `action_bar_container` though I'm using `ActionBarActivity` from `appcompat-v7` (r21.0.3). I checked and found `actionViewResId` returns positive value.

Comment: I don't think there is a need for this code anymore, because you already have access to the actionbar view from the toolbar view.

Comment: I actually need to add a max line at ActionBar Title TextView but `this.findViewById(actionViewResId)` returns null. I even used `getWindow().getDecorView()` instead of `this` and `action_bar_title` with no luck, though in both case `actionViewResId` returns a value. Could you suggest me how do I get that. 
*EDIT*
Sorry I didn't use `ToolBar`

Comment: let me check google code, maybe they are using different identifier for the actionbar view now.

Comment: I think the best solution for that is using Toolbar and customise the title of it, since the actionbar new layout doesn't have id's .

Comment: Thanks, but I wonder how `gen/R.class` gets `action_bar_title` and other related ids.

Comment: toolbar definitely some solution, but I'm wanting to achieve some small change to layout and don't want to integrate new toolbar from beginning, any update on this?

Comment: could you try with this id : R.id.action_bar  ??

Answer (score 3):

This will get the `Toolbar`/`ActionBar` when using the native `ActionBar`, your own `Toolbar` from appcompat, or the native `Toolbar` on Lollipop:

```
public static ViewGroup findActionBar(Activity activity) {
    int id = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar", "id", "android");
    ViewGroup actionBar = null;
    if (id != 0) {
        actionBar = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(id);
    }
    if (actionBar == null) {
        actionBar = findToolbar((ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)
                .getRootView());
    }
    return actionBar;
}

private static ViewGroup findToolbar(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewGroup toolbar = null;
    for (int i = 0, len = viewGroup.getChildCount(); i < len; i++) {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (view.getClass().getName().equals("android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar")
                || view.getClass().getName().equals("android.widget.Toolbar")) {
            toolbar = (ViewGroup) view;
        } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            toolbar = findToolbar((ViewGroup) view);
        }
        if (toolbar != null) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return toolbar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My activity extends AppCompatActivity

Following works:

findViewById(R.id.action_bar)