# how to hide/show OptionsMenu with animation

Tags: android, android-menu

I have a `NavigationDrawer` and hide/show the `OptionsMenu` (which is located on the bottom due to a split `ActionBar`) whenever the drawer gets opened/closed:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!isDrawerOpened) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I would like to hide the `Menu` with an animation, (for reference: like the animation used by the system when you call `ActionBar.hide()` ), however I found no way to access the `Layout` used for the `Menu` (so I could get a `View` object to apply the animation to). It seems there's no public API available to perform this, I wouldn't mind some reflection approach if I knew what to look for. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

looking at [this source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/881586ca84f2fb8e82faa9c8d645416d175d0f01/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/layout/abc_action_bar_decor_overlay.xml) I finally figured out how to access the `View` of a split `ActionBar` using a non-public identifier:

```
    private View getSplitActionBarView() {
    Window window = getWindow();
    View v = window.getDecorView();
    return v.findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("split_action_bar",
            "id", "android"));
}
```

Now I can create an `Animation`, set an `AnimationListener` and call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` as soon as the `Animation` ends. There's one problem left: doing this will let an ugly white rectangle at the place where the bottom part of the `ActionBar` was, this white rectangle will stay there until the `Animation` is complete. To get rid of it I would need to use   `<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>` in my style XML (or doing the same by code) to display the `ActionBar` in overlay mode. However this is not what I need.

**The question is now: is there any way to apply the overlay mode only to the split `ActionBar` (= the bottom part of the `ActionBar`)?**

Comment: Well...inflate()...creates the view...View view = getMenuInflater().inflate(...)...

Comment: @ElDuderino
that was the 1st thing I was thinking of, but.. `void android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(int menuRes, Menu menu)`

Comment: You can set an ActionView to the menu item, you can get the ActionView in onPrepareOptionsMenu and run your animation.

Comment: @ElDuderino yes I could probably access the `View` of a single `MenuItem`, but I need to apply the animation to the whole menu bar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21125631/2001247, maybe this will help you, I don't know much about the split actionbar...but it's a nice question, please post an answer if you can get it to work :)

Comment: @ElDuderino thanks for linking that, now I was able to get the `View` of the split `ActionBar`, I updated my question

Comment: You say it works with android:windowActionBarOverlay, a quick fix could be to use android:windowActionBarOverlay and set the top margin of your layout to the height of the actionbar...this way it would look like a normal actionbar and your anim could be working... but yeah, this is not a nice solution :)

Comment: @ElDuderino yep this is an option. However I gave up the idea, since you can't achieve a 2-way animation anyway. After calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` and hiding the bottom AB part with an animation, you will need to call it again to get the `Menu` back. In this case it appears immediately and there's no way to set an animation. The only way out would be using an own `View` instead of an `OptionsMenu`, it's not worth it however.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call invalidateOptionsMenu() when the drawer is open/close, like this

```
public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
     invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Now, onPrepareOptionsMenu() will be called,where you can hide/show the option menu like this..

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    // check if drawer is open
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

    for(int index = 0 ; index < menu.size() ; index ++){
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(index);
        if(menuItem != null) {
            // hide the menu items if the drawer is open
            menuItem.setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        }
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

You can hide all the menu or any of the required menu item.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the question.. I know how to hide the `Menu`, I asked how to hide it with a translate `Animation`.