# How can make Swip ActionBar-Tabs inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

I have a FragmentActivity and some fragment in my app.
i need to have Swip ActionBar-Tabs Just inside one fragment , but when i use ActionBar and ViewPager in my project to make Swip ActionBar Tab , make ActionBar in all of fragment No just in one,

hove i can make ActionBar just inside one fragment that not shown in other fragment?

```
    actionabar = getActionBar();
    actionabar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    /** Defining a listener for pageChange */
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {              
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            actionabar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);             
        }           
    };

    /** Setting the pageChange listner to the viewPager */
    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);

    /** Creating an instance of FragmentPagerAdapter */
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

    viewpager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
    actionabar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    Tab tab = actionabar.newTab().setText("My Friends").setTabListener(tabListener);
    actionabar.addTab(tab);
    tab = actionabar.newTab().setText("Android Version").setTabListener(tabListener);                               
    actionabar.addTab(tab);       
    tab = actionabar.newTab().setText("Android Phones").setTabListener(tabListener);                               
    actionabar.addTab(tab);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TabHost (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) instead of ActionBar navigation mode.

Comment: it possible to adding sweep inside TabHost?

Comment: I dont try it before but you could use ActionBar hover mode and animate ActionBar view(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023483/how-to-get-actionbar-view) using ObjectAnimator or ViewPropertyAnimator