# Push out/pull in ActionBar when ListView is scrolled

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The latest Google Newsstand App features an `ActionBar` and `ViewPager` tab bar which slowly eases out the top of the screen when the list below it is scrolled down. **Importantly, it eases out at the same speed the list is scrolled**. When the list is scrolled upwards the `ActionBar` eases back onto the screen, **again at the same speed the list is scrolled**.

*I am not referring to the `ActionBar` `hide()` and `show()` methods, instead I want to know how to hide and show the ActionBar at the same rate the list below it is scrolled.*

How is this achieved? All attempts at finding a documented solution have proven unsuccessful so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

Create a Fragment subclass that serves as an ActionBar replacement. Use an OnScrollListener to update the fragment's view's `translationY` after scroll events.

### Long Answer

After digging around the ActionBar source code, it seems that there is no public method for accessing the ActionBar container view. But where there's a will, [there's a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023483/how-to-get-actionbar-view).

You can grab a reference to the Action Bar's view using the following:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", "android");
View actionBarContainer = findViewById(resId);
```

**Disclaimer**: `action_bar_container` is a private ID, so it's subject to Google's whims. Use at your own risk.

Once you have the Action Bar's view, you can animate it however you'd like.

I hacked together [a semi-functional example](https://github.com/bamatson/PushPullActionBarDemo) if you're interested.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's incredibly good of you to provide a solution like that, thanks very much. As you said, I'll have to make a decision whether relying on action_bar_container not being changed in the future is worth the risk. Thanks.

Comment: I need to do a puch out/pull in action bar tabs.after imported that github,I can't see any java file inside src. can you check it and tell me.