# Espresso - How to match ActionBar visibility?

Tags: android-actionbar, android-espresso

Im trying to do a Espresso test for checking if actionbar is hidden/shown, but I cant seem to figure out how to match it with Espresso.onView(...). Afaik it doesnt have a id, right?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

The action bar view has an ID but it's not exposed. We can get it with `getIdentifier`:

```
Resources resources = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getResources();
int actionBarId = resources.getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", "android");
onView(withId(actionBarId)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Code adapted from this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21125631/714009). I think this will work but I haven't tested it.

Comment: This code works for me when I changed `android` by `getPackageName()`.