# Status bar background stays on screen when entering immersive mode?

Tags: android, statusbar, android-immersive

I've been searching everywhere but I'm at a loss about that : trying to activate immersive mode on a project;
Nearly everything works fine, except the background of my status bar always stays there, spoiling the immersion...
I have included a screenshot of the screen before and after activating the immersive mode, and set the "colorPrimaryDark" to full green for max contrast :
[screenshots showing the background of the status bar when nothing should be there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOD9f.jpg)
The code I used and reinserted in a blank project to isolate this problem comes straight from the google dev examples, in my MainActivity, I have :

```
private final String TAG = "DEBUG::" + this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private final int INITIAL_HIDE_DELAY = 1500;
private View decorView;
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //setting needed decorView for fullscreen behavior
    decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(onSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener);
}
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Log.i(TAG, "onWindowFocusChanged::hasFocus = " + hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {// When the window gains focus, hide the system UI.
        delayedHide(INITIAL_HIDE_DELAY);
    } else {// When the window loses focus, cancel any pending hide action.
        mHideHandler.removeMessages(0);
    }
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    Log.i(TAG, "hideSystemUI");
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
    uiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    uiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
    uiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    uiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    uiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;
    uiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
};

private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
    Log.i(TAG, "delayedHide");
    mHideHandler.removeMessages(0);
    mHideHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, delayMillis);
}

private View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener onSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener =
        new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                    // The system bars are visible
                    getSupportActionBar().show();
                    delayedHide(INITIAL_HIDE_DELAY);
                } else {
                    // The system bars are NOT visible
                    getSupportActionBar().hide();
                }
            }
        };
```

I wonder if my problem might come from layout or style files, but those are raw from project generation...
I hope someone out there can point me to where I failed!
Thanks in advance!

EDIT : I found that removing : `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from my activity's layout file allows a real fullscreen mode, but then, my ActionBar is partly hidden behind the StatusBar -when showing. Could it be that when I set my `getSupportActionBar().show();` in `onSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener`, it gets drawn too soon?

EDIT 2 : How I understand this so far is that I only have 2 choices regarding the position/size of my content (action bar included) :
top of the screen, which will show the actionBar partially hidden by the statusbar,
or below the statusBar's bottom, which will leave me with a "hole" when the statusBar is hidden -_-
I am now looking for a solution to animate the ActionBar off-screen/on-screen by myself inside my `onSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` method, but can't find a way to grab its View to do so, solutions posted there https://stackoverflow.com/a/21125631/6463888 seem out of date...

Answer (score 1):

So,
the way I solved this may seem a bit stretched, but I'm only a beginner, so feel free to comment!
I don't use `getSupportActionBar().show();` or `getSupportActionBar().hide();` anymore, but I managed to grab the View that contains the ActionBar which is an AppBarLayout, and I animated this View instead. So I call a small function `animateActionBarInOrOut` to animate it on or off screen inside `onSystemUiVisibilityChange` :

```
    private void animateActionBarInOrOut(boolean appears){
    Log.i(TAG, "animateActionBarInOrOut::actual position = " + toolbar.getY());
      if(appears){
       toolbar.animate().translationY(48).alpha(1); // move it out of the screen
      }else{
       toolbar.animate().translationY(-48).alpha(0); // move it out of the screen
      }
    }
```

Although this is not exactly an answer to the initial question, it works as a solution to the problem, one just has to move the content accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem today. But I didn't solve this issue by `setSystemUiVisibility`. I solve it using following method:

1. hide:enter full screen

   mActivity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
2. show:normal display

   mActivity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Answer (score 0):

Hi your problem is caused by StatusBar nature, it has a separate layout from your main content and you need to set his color manually. For example when you call onSystemUiVisibilityChange() you can take the color of your background and, after set the color of StatusBar with that color. This is a workaround to avoid 2 different background colors.

Comment: Well, actually, my purpose is to hide it completely, I thought the whole purpose of this immersive mode was to fill the screen with my content, while hiding the status and navigation bar... I don't want to change its background color, I just want it to disappear like the navigation bar does...

Comment: Mmmmmmmm yes I understand, Did you try to use toolbar.hide(), instead getSupportActionBar().hide() ?

Comment: afaik, there is no hide() method for the Toolbar object... I just edited my question to reflect my current position...